# How to Stop Getting Email Sent Confirmation Mail In Php Email

Tags: php, email

I have got this code :

```
<?php
//Fetching Values from URL
$name = $_POST['name1'];
$email = $_POST['email1'];
$message = $_POST['message1'];
$contact = $_POST['contact1'];
//sanitizing email
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
//After sanitization Validation is performed
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
$subject = $name;
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From:' . $email. "\r\n"; // Sender's Email
$headers .= 'Cc:' . $email. "\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender
...........
```

It is working good, But when any user is contacting though this form,
Then Both the admin(me) and User is Getting Same Email Confirmation...

I dont want to send email sent confirmation to the user,
can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Probably, there is problem in this line `$headers .= 'Cc:' . $email. "\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender`, delete it

Comment: but removing is not a solution for you question (well, it works, but you loose copy). check my answer

Answer (score 1):

delete this line:

```
$headers .= 'Cc:' . $email. "\r\n";  // Carbon copy to Sender
```

(the one with a comment saying "**Carbon copy to Sender**").

Answer (score 1):

Removing `CC:` is quite rough solution as you are loosing your copies. So instead of using `CC:` (carbon copy) header, to get copy sent to more users you should either send your copy as separate mail, or use `BCC:` (**blind** carbon copy) header which will be stripped by destination mail server, so recipient will not see it, and will not be able to reply to that address.

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers .= 'Cc:' . $email. "\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender
```

remove this line from your code.